# Installing Asus USB-AC56 Adapter on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus

I'm trying to get this ASUS USB-AC56 adapter installed on Ubuntu 17.10. I have upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04. The Driver bundle from Github as well as proprietary drivers that came with the device are not working. Errors encountered during make are appended below.

```
              ^~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:302: recipe for target '/home/unispirited/DR_USB_AC56_4314_Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/unispirited/DR_USB_AC56_4314_Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1546: recipe for target '_module_/home/unispirited/DR_USB_AC56_4314_Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/unispirited/DR_USB_AC56_4314_Linux/RTL8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505/driver/rtl8812AU_linux_v4.3.13_14061.20150505] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.13.0-16-generic'
Makefile:1622: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

On the Github driver `make` and `sudo make install` works but 
`sudo modprobe 8812au` gives

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error
```

please help in getting the Wifi Adapter to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tether or whatever means possible, I suggest that you do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
sudo modprobe 8812au
```

> Makefile:1622: recipe for target 'modules' failed

In the case of the driver you attempted to compile, if the process fails at 'make,' then all further steps will fail as well.

EDIT: Let’s try a different driver package. First, remove the package that won’t compile:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
```

Next, do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au.git
sudo cp -r rtl8812au  /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
sudo dkms add -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
sudo dkms install -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2
```

Reboot and tell us if the wireless is working.

Comment: sequential responses to the steps you suggested. I am connected to Internet on Ethernet
All packages are up to date.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error

Any further suggestions?

Comment: May we see: 'sudo dkms status` ? Thanks.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Device or resource busy


bbswitch, 0.8, 4.10.0-37-generic, x86_64: installed
bbswitch, 0.8, 4.13.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed
nvidia-384, 384.90, 4.13.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.13.0-16-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Any help from anyone on this?

Comment: Please see my edit above.

Comment: HELP NEEDED HERE   ***sudo dkms build -m rtl8812au -v 4.2.2 on ubuntu 18.10 gives >> Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...
Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' all KVER=4.15.0-23-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rtl8812au: 4.2.2 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-23-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.2.2/build/make.log for more information.
****
sudo dkms status
rtl8812au, 4.2.2: added
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-23-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: Please try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045765/usb-antenna-not-working-on-dell-optiplex-760-desktop/1045927#1045927