# USB Antenna Not Working on Dell Optiplex 760 Desktop?

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, dell

I have an issue very similar to ([Ubuntu 17.10 Drivers Not Found/Working Properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970283/ubuntu-17-10-drivers-not-found-working-properly/970352?noredirect=1#comment1705285_970352)), but this was done on a fresh install of Kubuntu 18.04. This desktop doesn't have an internal Wi-Fi card and I'm currently using an old wi-fi module to get an internet connection there. The main issue with the old wi-fi dongle is that it doesn't have the proper antenna to provide adequate wi-fi connectivity, as this desktop is in a remote location where ethernet cords cannot easily reach, and where wi-fi signals are faint at best.

I used the new wi-fi antenna, which is the source of the trouble, first, and folowed the steps layed out in ([Ubuntu 17.10 Drivers Not Found/Working Properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970283/ubuntu-17-10-drivers-not-found-working-properly/970352?noredirect=1#comment1705285_970352)) to try and get it to work. It didn't.

I made sure to not have the old wi-fi antenna in the USB slot while I was following the commands and only re-inserted it after completing all command and restarting the system and realizing that the steps were unsuccessful in being able to restore the USB antenna-driver functionality.

The New USB Antenna is the exact same as the one listed in ([Ubuntu 17.10 Drivers Not Found/Working Properly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/970283/ubuntu-17-10-drivers-not-found-working-properly/970352?noredirect=1#comment1705285_970352))

**Edit 0:** `sudo dkms status` yields

```
rtl8812au, 4.2.2: added 
rtl8812AU, 5: added
```

**Edit **: Output of `lsusb` (With Both USB Antennae in the USB ports)

```
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:a811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. Dell QuietKey Keyboard
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

**Edit 1:** Modprobe Info & Secure Boot

```
sarah@SciLabComp0:~$ sudo modprobe 8812au
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert '8812au': Exec format error
sarah@SciLabComp0:~$ modinfo 8812au | grep A811
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

Mokutil (The recommended way to check if secure boot is enabled based on another ask ubuntu question):

```
sarah@SciLabComp0:~$ mokutil --sb-state
EFI variables are not supported on this system
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have the 4.2.2 package downloaded on my 18.04 system. It will not 'make' without errors. I feel confident that you then tried the 5 version instead and it also didn't build properly for the same reasons. Let's clean them out:

```
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/5.2.9 --all
sudo rm /usr/src/rtl8812au-5.2.9
sudo dkms remove rtl8812au/4.2.2 --all
sudo rm /usr/src/rtl8812au-4.2.2
```

There is an rtl8812au-dkms package available in the official Ubuntu repositories. It installs without error for me in 18.04. I suggest that you try:

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Reboot.

**EDIT**: We see from your modinfo that the installed version doesn’t actually cover your 0bda:a811 device. Let’s remove it and try a different driver file:

```
sudo apt purge rtl8812au-dkms
sudo apt install git
git clone https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux.git
cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux
sudo make -f Makefile.dkms install
sudo modprobe rtl8812au
```

This driver clearly covers your device:

```
modinfo rtl8812au | grep A811

alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v0BDApA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
alias:          usb:v7392pA811d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in*
```

You should be all set.

Comment: It didn't work after reboot. New `sudo dkms status` says `rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-22-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-23-generic, x86_64: installed
`

Comment: Looks perfect so far. Please edit your question to show: `lsusb` with the antenna plugged in, of course.

Comment: Post Updated. I left the working USB inserted when I executed the `lsusb` command, is that ok?

Comment: Just fine. May we now see: `sudo modprobe 8812au` and also: `modinfo 8812au | grep A811` ??Secure Boot??

Comment: Exec format error; yikes! I will attack this later on tomorrow.

Comment: I'm just happy that someone who knows what they're doing is able to help me. These device issues are beyond my current level of understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words. Please see my edit above in a few minutes.

Comment: Worked wihtou a problem after restarting. Thank goodness, no more .5 MB/s connection! Would upvote twice if I could!