# WUSB6300 wireless not working

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, 19.10

I've been unsuccessful getting the WUSB6300 to work on Ubuntu 19.10.  I've executed the instructions at this [website](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642794/how-do-i-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux)

My output from lsusb is 
"*Bus 002 Device 009: ID 13b1:003f Linksys WUSB6300 802.11a/b/g/n/ac Wireless Adapter [Realtek RTL8812AU]*"

My output from lsmod shows the 8812au listed.  My output from lshw -C network doesn't show the WSUSB6300, 8812au, or any type of wireless adapter, only the Realtek PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller that's integral to the motherboard.

What am I missing?  I can't help thinking that there's something I'm not doing that would enable this dongle to be recognized and used.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT #1**
`modinfo 8812au |grep 003F`

> usb:v13B1p003Fd`*`dc`*`dsc`*`dp`*`ic`*`isc`*`ip`*`in`*`

`dmesg | grep -i rtl`

> [    1.504926] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: RTL8168evl/8111evl, 50:e5:49:b8:a6:98, XID 2c9, IRQ 34
>   [    6.978205] RTL871X: module init start
>   [    6.978206] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902
>   [    6.978206] RTL871X: build time: Apr 13 2020 13:46:32
>   [    7.094661] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8812au
>   [    7.094662] RTL871X: module init ret=0
>   [    7.190684] RTL871X: module init start
>   [    7.190685] RTL871X: rtl8812au v4.3.14_13455.20150212_BTCOEX20150128-51
>   [    7.190685] RTL871X: rtl8812au BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20150128-51
>   [    7.190693] Error: Driver 'rtl8812au' is already registered, aborting...
>   [    7.190697] RTL871X: module init ret=-16
>   [   17.308006] RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet r8169-700:00: attached PHY driver
>   [RTL8211E Gigabit Ethernet] (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-700:00, irq=IGNORE)

**EDIT #2**
`sudo updatedb && locate 8812au.ko`

> /usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/doc': Permission denied
>   /usr/bin/find: '/run/user/1000/gvfs': Permission denied
>   /usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/updates/dkms/8812au.ko
>   /usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/updates/dkms/rtl8812au.ko
>   /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux/1.0/5.3.0-46-generic/x86_64/module/rtl8812au.ko
>   /var/lib/dkms/rtl8812au/4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg/5.3.0-46-generic/x86_64/module/8812au.ko

`sudo dkms status`

> rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.3.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
>   rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0, 5.3.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed

**EDIT #3**
`sudo modprobe -r 8812au && sudo modprobe rtl8812au`
`lsmod`

> Module             Size     Used by
>   rtl8812au            1347584  0

Disconnected wired connection, removed/reinserted usb dongle, no change to network behavior, i.e. no wireless connection to local wireless router.

**EDIT #4**
`sudo modprobe -r rtl8812au && sudo modprobe 88au`
`lsmod`

> Module                  Size  Used by
>   8812au               1290240  0
>   cfg80211              712704  1 8812au

`iwconfig`

> lo        no wireless extensions.
>   enp7s0    no wireless extensions.

`sudo dkms status`

> rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.3.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
>   rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux, 1.0, 5.3.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed

Apologies, I should clarify..this "radio button" is selectable for enable & disable. I've done both, with no difference in connection, i.e. no wireless established after either enabling or disabling

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal commands: `modinfo 8812au | grep 003F` and also: `dmesg | grep -i rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Please add: `sudo updatedb && locate 8812au.ko` and also: `sudo dkms status` You may have two different drivers loading and conflicting.

Comment: @chili555 - Is the problem actually that I have two drivers conflicting? If so, what would be the steps to remove the rtl8812au vs the rtl8812AU?

Comment: We don't yet know if that is the actual problem. Let's unload one of the two and see if it helps: `sudo modprobe -r 8812au && sudo modprobe rtl8812au` Is Secure Boot disabled in the BIOS/EFI?

Comment: Let's try instead the other driver: `sudo modprobe -r rtl8812au && sudo modprobe 8812au` Do *NOT* remove and reinsert the USB dongle. Any change/improvement?

Comment: I will, but a question occurs to me...what indication of functionality should I be looking for?  I'm not disconnecting the Cat5e cable and leaving the USB dongle in place, and I'm not sure what I should be watching for?  thanks again for the assist :-)

Comment: I also ran the previous modinfo & dmesg commands, with the same results as initially observed.  Another data point that might/not be useful: When opening/interacting with the Software Updater in Ubuntu, I tried enabling the WUSB6300 driver as an option under the "Additional Drivers" tab.  Ubuntu appeared to be performing some kind of action before returning control...maybe installing rtl8812au v4.3.8_12175.20140902, which appears to still be conflicting with rtl8812au v4.3.14 ?  Anyway, that radio button was disabled for the entire set of operations & commands we've been working through.

Comment: "Anyway, that radio button was disabled for the entire set of operations & commands we've been working through." That is probably why the wireless doesn't work! Please press it and try again. The action we are looking for is for the Network Manager icon offer to connect to networks it sees.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with 18.04 and Linksys WUSB6300.

These are the steps I used to get up and persist reboots:

#### On Ubuntu Server

Install the tools:

```
sudo apt install wireless-tools && sudo apt install wpasupplicant
```

Install the driver:

```
sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms
```

Now open`.yaml`file in netplan for editing:

```
sudo vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Replace `wlan0` with the name of your adapter (do `ifconfig` to find it).

Netplan file should look similar to this:

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        eno1:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: true
            access-points:
                "my_essid":
                    password: "my_password"
```

Now generate and debug:

```
sudo netplan --debug generate
```

Apply the configuration:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

Now remove ethernet wire and reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

**Info**:
My `sudo dkms status` output:

```
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 4.15.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
```

And your output has 2 versions of drivers installed. You must uninstall `rtl8812AU_8821AU`.

**Note**:
Connection and ip established after `netplan generate`. Omitting `optional: true` for `ethernets` will prevent persistence upon reboots.

#### For Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 through 20.04:

Update the package database:

```
sudo apt update
```

Install required packages:

```
sudo apt install git build-essential
```

Download the driver:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/gnab/rtl8812au
```

Go to the directory:

```
cd rtl8812au
```

Do the next commands consecutively:

```
sudo make clean
sudo make  
sudo make uninstall 
sudo make install
```

Reboot and insert USB wireless stick

- Persists reboots
- Works for WUSB6300

Comment: Please note - I originally was unable to locate a wlan interface via the `lshw -C network` command.  The only output was the integrated PCI gigabit ethernet interface, not the WSUB6300 or any other wireless interface.

Comment: where would I locate Netplan to compare to the example provided?  How do I uninstall the conflicting driver you?  what's the actual order of steps, uninstall first or install rtl8812au-dkms and then uninstall?

Comment: install **wireless-tools** as suggested above and edit your question to show output of `iwconfig`. Netplan is located in `/etc`, to see the default neplan file you have to do `cd /etc/netplan` then command `ls` and look for a file ending in `.yaml`; this would be your network configuration file. As per the rtl8812AU_8821AU driver, yes you would need to uninstall this first and chili555 would definitely know how to do this.

Comment: I tried searching for a way to uninstall the rtl8812AU_8821AU driver that I installed previously using the instructions from this website (https://askubuntu.com/questions/642794/how-do-i-get-the-linksys-wusb6300-wireless-adapter-to-work-on-linux), but I'm not finding anything.  Is that a question I should post separate from this thread?

Comment: @kkyucon Please explain why you recommend netplan, generally apprpriate for servers, instead of Network Manager. Why do you evidently suspect that Network Manager is the issue? Why do you recommend installing a *third* version of the driver? Aren't nettools and wpa-supplicant already installed in a desktop environment in Ubuntu?

Comment: @chili555 WUSB6300 just does not work with driver rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux and Network Manager. I have tried **your** countless contributing efforts to get this to work in the past 2 years. As you suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045765/usb-antenna-not-working-on-dell-optiplex-760-desktop/1045927#1045927) for installing the driver `sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms` from official repository; this just works. **Note**, I have tried Network Manager `renderer: NetworkManager`.

Comment: @chili555 for info 19.10 does ship with neplan

Comment: @kkyucon I am fully aware that it does; however, in a desktop installation, it points to Network Manager as should Dartheric.

Comment: @kkyucon "As you suggested here for installing the driver sudo apt install rtl8812au-dkms from official repository; this just works" That was directed at the device 0bda:a811 but here we are addressing 13b1:003f. What is the evidence that this "just works"?

Comment: Thanks for your help! I finally got my WUSB6300 working on Mint 20.
I tried the driver suggested by the Drivers manager, but it doesn't work.
The helpful `sudo dkms status` command showed I had two conflicting drivers installed. I first uninstalled them with `sudo apt-get remove rtl8812au-dkms` then `sudo dkms remove 8812au/4.2.2 --all`. Then your final procedure (from "Update the system: `sudo apt update`" till the end) was enough and worked perfectly. However, your last command should be, of course, `sudo make install` instead of `sudo install`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @gieffa. Thank you for `sudo make install`. My answer has been updated.